# SharePoint Service setup tutorial

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint Service setup. I need a tutorial for SharePoint Service 3.0 setup for Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I need a setup tutorial which is not for Active Directory (or domain controller) based user management, I want to store user credentials into a SQL Server database or using Windows built-in account (on the machine where SharePoint Service is installed).

Any recommended readings?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Asking for tutorials is generally not a good idea, as the tutorials get out of date quickly, and are of little use to future visitors. Instead, if you have a specific question about where you're stuck, feel free to [ask another question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) outlining exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to read up on SharePoint and Forms Based Authentication using the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider. Google is full of tutorials when you search for those terms.

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sharepoint+AspNetSqlMembershipProvider&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)

Comment: Thanks Colin, could you recommend me a tutorial for installation without dependent on AD? The Google links describes only how to configure Forms Authentication Part.

Comment: When using the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider, you specifically store your end users in SQL Server. 

The Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 installation can just be run, use the local "Network Service" account to run your services if you are ABSOLUTELY sure you are going to use Forms based Authentication ONLY.
(Sharepoint timer service etc. can only be run as Windows users, the actual users visiting your site(s) can then be authenticated through the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider)

Answer (score 1):

Users should be able to log in to Sharepoint by using local accounts. You will have to log in using

```
Server Name\User Name
```

So if you username was Luke, and the server name was Sharepoint you would enter

```
Sharepoint\Luke
```

in the username field.

I was recently trialing the product in a non-AD environment, and this worked fine for me.

Comment: Could you recommend me a tutorial for installation without dependent on AD?

Comment: Not specifically.

I would start with some of the MS deployment documentation.

Something like this http://office.microsoft.com/download/afile.aspx?AssetID=AM101638661033 would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Some points of reading for you...

[Deploy Office SharePoint Server 2007 in a server farm environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc303428.aspx)

- This will take you through all of the installation steps to ensure a successful installation.

[Deploy a simple farm on the Windows Server 2008 operating system (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc263408.aspx)

- While the previous articles are more designed for Windows 2003, this article is only for Windows 2008. However it only describes deployment to a 'simple farm' (i.e. two servers, one for SharePoint and the other for SQL Server).

[Configure forms-based authentication (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc262201.aspx)

- This shows how to set up the ASP.NET membership database for authentication.

Also see: [Installation Resource Center for SharePoint Server 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sharepointserver/cc963997.aspx) and [Authentication Resource Center for SharePoint Products and Technologies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sharepointserver/bb735938.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

George, do you know about [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/default.aspx)?

Comment: Sure, John. I did not find a tutorial which suits my needs, especially which is not for Active Directory (or domain controller) based user management, I want to store user credentials into a SQL Server database or using Windows built-in account (on the machine where SharePoint Service is installed). Any recommendations?

Comment: George, is this your first SharePoint installation? If so, then I'd leave the customization along for now.